# How do you append JSON object data to the next available row so that each key value goes to the corresponding column that matches?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

So I have a JSON object and I just want to append the to the next row the data in it so that the value goes to whatever column matches the key.

Comment: Unfortunate, I cannot image your current situation and your goal from `So I have a JSON object and I just want to append the to the next row the data in it so that the value goes to whatever column matches the key.`. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect and your current script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function loadData() {
  let obj=JSON.parse(your json string);
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');//sheet name
  const hdrrow=1;//header row
  const hA=sh.getRange(hdrrow,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];//header values at least some of which should match keys
  let row=new Array(hA.length);//make array same length as header row
  hA.forEach((h,i)=>{
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(h)) {
      row[i]=obj[h];
    }
  });
  sh.appendRow(row);
}
```

I assume string is in the form

```
'{"COL1":6,"COL2":12,"COL3":4,"COL4":21,"COL5":6,"COL6":19,"COL7":23,"COL8":20,"COL9":2,"COL10":18}'
```